# Java reads 10 as 2 characters, how to change this

Tags: java, arrays, char

This program works when the `int` array does not need to count up to 10. My problem is that `charat` is reading 10 as two different chars, which they are. How am i able to make an exception for 10? for example, the program below, when you type in 5 people, the program prints out from 6-1, as the 1 is reading from the first char of 10. When you type in 6, `charat` is reading the 0, so it prints out 6-0.

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.util.*;

public class JavaApplication2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the amount of people in your group, up to 6");
        int num = input.nextInt();

        if (num > 6) {
            System.out.println("You have exceeded the maximum amount of people allowed.");
        }

        int highest = num - 1;
        String available = "";
        String booking = " ";
        int[] RowA = {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

        for (int i = 0; i < RowA.length; i++) {
            if (RowA[i] == 0) {
                available = available + (i + 1);
            }
            if (available.length() > booking.length()) {
                booking = available;
                System.out.println(booking);
            } else if (RowA[i] == 1) {
                available = "";
            }
        }


        if (num <= booking.length()) {
            char low = booking.charAt(0);
            char high = booking.charAt(highest);
            System.out.println("There are seats from " + low + " - " + high + ".");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The desired seat amount is not available. The maximum amount on Row is " + booking.length());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the variable `booking` represent? It sounds like you are trying to use the characters of a String as numbers. Perhaps you should use an `int[]` instead of a String.

Comment: You should rethink how you have designed your code.  I won't use a String as a collection as you will get into all sorts of problem.  I would also check your "booking" loop works as I can see a number of issues with it. You could use an `int[]` but a `List<Integer>` will be simpler if you don't know how many elements you want to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you're doing is a code smell called a Primitive Obsession. You're using Strings where you should instead be using a more complex data type, such as a collection or array:

```
import java.util.*;

public class JavaApplication2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the amount of people in your group, up to 6");
        int num = input.nextInt();

        if (num > 6) {
            System.out.println("You have exceeded the maximum amount of people allowed.");
        }

        int highest = num - 1;
        ArrayList<Integer> available = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Integer[] booking = new Integer[0];
        int[] RowA = {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

        for (int i = 0; i < RowA.length; i++) {
            if (RowA[i] == 0) {
                available.add(i + 1);
            }
            if (available.size() > booking.length) {
                booking = available.toArray(booking);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(booking));
            } else if (RowA[i] == 1) {
                available.clear();
            }
        }


        if (num <= booking.length) {
            int low = booking[0];
            int high = booking[highest];
            System.out.println("There are seats from " + low + " - " + high + ".");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The desired seat amount is not available. The maximum amount on Row is " + booking.length);
        }
    }
}
```

Using collections and arrays means that you don't have to worry about `charAt` and the number of decimal places because you're actually manipulating `int` and `Integer` types - which will keep track of their decimals on their own.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an input string:

Since booking is a string, it is more convenient to capture the values of low and high to integers using a substring. for example like this:

```
if (num <= booking.length()) {
    int lineIndex = booking.indexOf("-");
    if (lineIndex < 0)
        lineIndex = booking.indexOf("/");

    int low = Integer.parseInt(booking.substring(0, lineIndex);
    int high = Integer.parseInt(booking.substring(lineIndex+1, booking.length());
}
```

System.out.println() will parse the integers correct in the form they are in now. The extra checks are in case you are using more separation symbols than just the '-'.

Comment: wait a sec netbeans says it cannot find the symbol int

Comment: int is a primitive datatype, it should be recognized by netbeans. Integer is an object that starts with a capital. Could it be you accidentally typed int with a capital (Int)?